# C#, Structure, JSON

Tags: c#, json, database, structure, json-deserialization

I have some JSON files and structure. In static void Initialization() I want to put information from json file to Data[i]. How can I do that?

```
private static Student[] Data = new Student[99];
        struct Student
        {
            public int Id;
            public string FullName;
            public DateTime BirthdayDate;
            public string Institute;
            public string Group;
            public string Course;
            public double AvgMark;
            public string form_ed;
            public string lvl_ed;
            public int zadolzh;

            public Student(int Id, string FullName, DateTime BirthdayDate, string Institute, string Group, string Course, double AvgMark, string form_ed, string lvl_ed, int zadolzh)
            {
                this.Id = Id;
                this.FullName = FullName;
                this.BirthdayDate = BirthdayDate;
                this.Institute = Institute;
                this.Group = Group;
                this.Course = Course;
                this.AvgMark = AvgMark;
                this.form_ed = form_ed;
                this.lvl_ed = lvl_ed;
                this.zadolzh = zadolzh;
            } 
        }
static void Initialization()
{
        
}
```

Comment: [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) would be the easiest way

Comment: And using a class instead of a struct would be more conventional here.

Comment: In you Initalization method, loop your json files, deserialize each and put the student object returned into the students array.

Comment: show your json please

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JSON.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and use a similar code. instead of `student` you can assign it to your array item.

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
var student = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(json);
```

I assume your JSON is:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "fullName": null,
  "birthdayDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
  "institute": null,
  "group": null,
  "course": null,
  "avgMark": 0.0,
  "form_ed": null,
  "lvl_ed": null,
  "zadolzh": 0
}
```

A more optimized solution will be to use the below JSON and deserialize it to `student[]`.

```
[{
    "id": 0,
    "fullName": null,
    "birthdayDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "institute": null,
    "group": null,
    "course": null,
    "avgMark": 0.0,
    "form_ed": null,
    "lvl_ed": null,
    "zadolzh": 0
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "fullName": null,
    "birthdayDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "institute": null,
    "group": null,
    "course": null,
    "avgMark": 0.0,
    "form_ed": null,
    "lvl_ed": null,
    "zadolzh": 0
}]
string json = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
var students = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student[]>(json);
```

As suggested by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), better to use class in place of struct here, you only need to replace the `struct` keyword with `class`.